# Unable to restart numbering list in a word document using openxml namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk

There is a word document with multiple tables which contains two columns. Column2 can have Hyperlinks, screenshots, nested tables, bulletin list and so on.

The Code should read the Column2 content and write it into another word document in a numbering list format. Since there are multiple tables, **Numbering list should be restarted for each table.**
[Sample input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjd7o.png)
[Expected Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i2YK.png)

- When numbering list is achieved, Numbering list restart is not working.
- When numbering list restart is achieved, format of the cell is getting decomposed.
  your text`Expecting the C# code using`openxml`namespaces,`using DocumentFormat.OpenXml; using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing`

Here is the code where numbering restart is working and format is getting decomposed.

'''lang-C#

```
public static void createDoc(string Filename, string opfolder)

    {

        string b = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmsstt");
        b = opfolder + b + ".docx";
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(Filename);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument indoc =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))

            using (WordprocessingDocument opdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(b, 0))
            
            MainDocumentPart inMainPart = indoc.MainDocumentPart;
            Body inbody = inMainPart.Document.Body;
            MainDocumentPart opMainPart = opdoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
            opMainPart.Document = new Document();
            Body outputBody = new Body();
            IEnumerable<Table> tables = inbody.Descendants<Table>();
            NumberingDefinitionsPart numberingpart = opMainPart.AddNewPart<NumberingDefinitionsPart>();
            numberingpart.Numbering = new Numbering();
            Numbering numbering = numberingpart.Numbering;
            int listindex = 1;
            int columnIndex = 1;
            foreach (Table table in tables)
            {
                var columnCells = table.Elements<TableRow>()
                Select(row => row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAtOrDefault(columnIndex))
                Where(cell => cell != null);
                foreach (var cell in columnCells)
                {
                    if (cell.InnerText.ToLower().StartsWith("Column2"))
                    { continue; }
                    Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
                    newParagraph.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties(new NumberingProperties(
                    new NumberingLevelReference()(Val = 0),
                    new Numberingid()(Val = listindex J));
                    foreach (Paragraph p in cell.Descendants<Paragraph>())
                    {
                        foreach (var run in p.Elements<Run>())
                        {
                            Run newrun = (Run)run.CloneNode(true);
                            newParagraph.Append(newrun);
                        }
                        outputBody.Append(newParagraph);
                    }
                }
            }
            listindex++;
            opMainPart.Document.Body = outputBody;
            opMainPart.Document.Save();

        }
    }
```

'''

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654196/using-openxml-numbered-lists-with-restart-of-numbering-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment135223726_76654196